# jQuery .remove() not working to remove JQuery var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the $movieDiv that is appended when clicking "#buttonLicensedMovie". It appends to the html just fine and the same button hides just fine, as it should. The issue I am having is when I click the anchor tag with id "licensedMovie1, the $movieDiv does not remove and the "#buttonLicensedMovie1" does not show back up. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#buttonLicensedMovie1").click(function(){
        var $movieDiv = '<p class="header">Becoming An Agent</p>\n<iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>\r\n<br/><a id="licensedMovie1" class="video-close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close Video</a>';
        $("#movieLicensedWrapper1").append($movieDiv);
        $("#buttonLicensedMovie1").hide();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#licensedMovie1").click(function(){
        var $movieDiv = '<p class="header">Becoming An Agent</p>\n<iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>\r\n<br/><a id="licensedMovie1" class="video-close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close Video</a>';
        $("#movieLicensedWrapper1").remove($movieDiv);
        $("#buttonLicensedMovie1").show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="buttonLicensedMovie1" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><h5>Becoming an Agent <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></h5></button>
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="movieLicensedWrapper1">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: that's because [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) expects a selector, not the entire element definition

Comment: Before using jQuery, learn about the DOM, and you'll change your entire approach to this problem and will probably find that jQuery isn't needed.

Comment: Here is the issue - I have to use JavaScript and/or JQuery to dynamically bring in videos because there are around 20-30 videos on this page that will significantly drag down the page load time if they are embedded, so I don't want them loaded into the DOM at page load time. I have tried many different ways to remove the appended HTML content but for some reason it isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

You could use (won't work in your case because not everything is inside the `p`):

```
$("#movieLicensedWrapper1 p.header").remove();
```

Or you create a global variable and assign the value with:

```
$movieDiv = $.parseHTML('...');
```

And then you can remove with just:

```
$movieDiv.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append it works fine because you are just adding html. However, when you want to remove you need to select the DOM element. Try this instead:

```
var $movieDiv = $('#movieLicensedWrapper1').find('.header');
$movieDiv.remove();
```